# Combine two columns in SQL for WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

In my SQL, I am using the `WHERE` and `LIKE` clauses to perform a search. However, I need to perform the search on a combined value of two columns - `first_name` and `last_name`:

`WHERE customers.first_name + customers.last_name LIKE '%John Smith%'`

This doesn't work, but I wondered how I could do something along these lines?

I have tried to do seperate the search by the two columns, like so:

`WHERE customers.first_name LIKE '%John Smith%' OR customers.last_name LIKE '%John Smith%'`

But obviously that will not work, because the search query is the combined value of these two columns.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use the following:

```
WHERE CONCAT(customers.first_name, ' ', customers.last_name) LIKE '%John Smith%'
```

Note that in order for this to work as intended, first name and last name should be trimmed, i.e. they should not contain leading or trailing whitespaces. It's better to trim strings in PHP, before inserting to the database. But you can also incorporate trimming into your query like this:

```
WHERE CONCAT(TRIM(customers.first_name), ' ', TRIM(customers.last_name)) LIKE '%John Smith%'
```

Answer (score 3):

I would start with something like this:

```
WHERE customers.first_name LIKE 'John%' AND customers.last_name LIKE 'Smith%'
```

This would return results like: `John Smith`, `Johnny Smithy`, `Johnson Smithison`, because the percentage sign is only at the end of the `LIKE` clause.  Unlike `'%John%'` which could return results like: `aaaaJohnaaaa`, `aaaSmithaaa`.

Comment: This should be more efficient than running a concat first and then comparing.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM customers 
WHERE concat(first_name,' ',last_name) like '%John Smith%';
```

reference:
[MySQL string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

Answer (score 0):

I have six div each div have individual id , if  one  id is passed that particular div will change the color if  button is submitted.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).