# Combine two fields in SQL for WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've found this [question on the Stackoverflow site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325170/combine-two-columns-in-sql-for-where-clause/15139588#15139588) but it only answers MySQL server. My question is very similar except I am working on MS SQL server instead.

Here's what I've tried and it's not working. Any help is much appreciated.

```
SELECT *
WHERE ([fstName] + ' ' + [lstName]) LIKE '%John Smith%'
FROM [usersTable]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`WHERE` clause must come after the `FROM` clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM   Advancement.dbo.classNotes
WHERE  fstName + ' ' + lstName LIKE '%John Smith%'
```

bad side of this is that it doesn't use index causing to perform full table scan -- which is slow.

Comment: Many thanks for the immediate response. That works! I didn't think the order matters.

Comment: Even though the question is only for SQL-Server, it is noteworthy to mention, it does not work in mySql