# How to match pass strings to a php function that checks mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have written a function which takes a database and a string and finds a match in the database and returns the corresponding values of book ISBNS..However it's not working for me....I think the problem is when I am matching the names....so for example I have Jack Thorne....When I pass it to the function am I supposed to put a comma in between since am getting the first name Jack from the first name column and the last name from the last name column....I have tried deliberately passing it a name of an author I know exists but it's not returning anything..Please help 
Here is the function

```
function booksByAuthor($db,$author){
    $query='SELECT isbn FROM books_authors WHERE author_id = (SELECT author_id FROM authors WHERE first_name,last_name = :author)';
    $statement = $db->prepare($query); 
    $statement->bindValue(':author', $author);
    $statement->execute(); 
    $isbns= $statement->fetchAll();  
    $statement->closeCursor();  
    return $isbns; 
}
```

Comment: `WHERE x,y=z` is a meaningless statement. You mean `WHERE x=z OR y=z` presumably.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine two columns in SQL for WHERE clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325170/combine-two-columns-in-sql-for-where-clause)

Comment: I'm not sure this is the best schema. A lot of authors don't have both first and last names, plus splitting the name up is often non-trivial. How do you split [Cyrano de Bergerac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrano_de_Bergerac)? [Arthur C. Clarke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_C._Clarke)? [Plato](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plato)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$query='SELECT isbn FROM books_authors 
WHERE author_id IN 
(SELECT author_id FROM authors WHERE first_name =:author OR last_name = :author)';
```

the equals is changed to IN - since the SELECT author_id ... statement will create several results.

the first_name =:author OR last_name = :author - to get results that will look into both first_name or last_name column.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that actually pointed me into the right direction, since I was passing the name as one string I decided to explode it and then use your querry..It worked...