# Is there a way to create a temporary column for a single query in Activerecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Let's say we have a ChessPiece class with the following migration.

```
create_table :chess_pieces do |t|
  t.string  :type
  t.integer :row
  t.integer :column
  t.integer :game_id, index: true
end
```

If a Bishop wanted to move from (0,0) to (7,7) then I need to check each space in between the two positions for other pieces that might be blocking my Bishop. IE if there was a Pawn on (5,5).

I could query the database for EACH position that might have a blocking piece like this:

```
pieces = []
8.times do |i|
  pieces << ChessPiece.where(game_id: @game_id, row: i, column: i)
end
```

But I want to cut down on queries. Alternatively, I could grab ***all*** the chess pieces for a game and iterate over them in Ruby, but that also seems inefficient. What I'd like to do is tell the database to combine the `row` and `column` columns together into the form "row-column" and call it `position`. That way I could run something like the following query:

```
ChessPiece.where(game_id: @game_id, position: ["1-1", "2-2", "3-3"])
```

How do I dynamically create this new column so I can run something like the above query? (Assume I can't just edit the database schema.)

Comment: You could do a concat on the two columns and put them in the WHERE clause like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325170/combine-two-columns-in-sql-for-where-clause

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.select` to create any select statement you want:

```
@chess_pieces = ChessPiece.select(
  "chess_pieces.*", 
  "CONCAT(chess_pieces.row, '-', chess_pieces.column) AS position"
)
```

When you use an alias the column in the result will be available as an attribute on the model:

```
@chess_pieces.first.position
```

You can also use column aliases in the WHERE, ORDER and GROUP clauses on some (PG, MySQL) but not all dbs:

```
ChessPiece.select(
  "chess_pieces.*", 
  "CONCAT(chess_pieces.row, '-', chess_pieces.column) AS position"
).where('position = ?', '1-1')
 .group('position')
 .order('position ASC')
```

On those who don't support it you need to concat, aggregate or whatever it is you are doing in-situ.

```
ChessPiece.order("CONCAT(chess_pieces.row, '-', chess_pieces.column)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not make this a permanent column?

Add a position column of type integer.
Create a before save hook that sets the position to `row * 10 + column`

You can now query the position column

```rb
ChessPiece.where(game_id: @game_id, position: [11, 22, 33])
```

If you want you can also override the position= to also set the column and row. Allowing you to use it for writes as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a helper to your `ChessPiece` model to simplify building the correct query. Something like this should do the trick:

```
class ChessPiece < ApplicationRecord
  def self.matches_position(*positions)
    return none if positions.empty?

    constraints = positions.map do |row, column|
      arel_table[:row].eq(row).and(arel_table[:column].eq(column))
    end

    where(constraints.reduce(:or))
  end
end

ChessPiece.where(game_id: @game_id).matches_position([1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3])
```

This should result in the SQL (syntax might differ based on the database used):

```sql
SELECT "chess_pieces".*
FROM "chess_pieces"
WHERE "chess_pieces"."game_id" = 1
  AND ("chess_pieces"."row" = 1 AND "chess_pieces"."column" = 1
       OR "chess_pieces"."row" = 2 AND "chess_pieces"."column" = 2
       OR "chess_pieces"."row" = 3 AND "chess_pieces"."column" = 3)
```